# Transfer Windows 10 Pro OEM upgrade license to another Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, license

I've done online upgrade of Windows 10 Home to Pro on my Surface Pro 7.
The license is associated to my Microsoft account.

I understand this upgrade license is not transferable to another PC because it's not retail license however it should still be valid for this PC even after resale?

Unfortunately it would require that I log in on the PC every time after factory reset which is not feasible after resale.

Is there some way to transfer this license to another account or convert it to a key?

Comment: You can disable activations via your online Microsoft account, and iIIRC, it's under Devices _(I may be misremembering the name)_

Comment: “Is there some way to transfer this license to another account or convert it to a key?” -  No

Comment: OEM licenses are bound to the device, not the user.

Comment: Thanks but please make a full answer using button below so I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per @tetsujin's answer [Transfer Windows 10 Pro OEM upgrade license to another Microsoft account](https://superuser.com/questions/1699340/transfer-windows-10-pro-oem-upgrade-license-to-another-microsoft-account#comment2615330_1699340):

> OEM licenses are bound to the device, not the user.